# Deploy and start .NET service on multiple Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, windows-server-2012

I have a service written in C# that relies on features in .NET 4.5 that are not yet supported in any version of mono, so I have to use Windows servers.  In other cases to deploy a network service I would just SCP a jar/tar/whatever over and then SSH over the deployment process, and that can be made a part of an sh script that can distribute to wherever.  But because this is Windows, I don't have those tools and I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to deploy this to 20 (or more) different servers.

So I see that there is a publish process in MSVS 2012, but it seems to make use of Windows file shares or else I'm supposed to send it to a website of some kind(???) but it doesn't look like it has any way of starting it even if I could figure out how to get it there.

Is there some product that does this in Windows or would it be easier for me to just install an SSH server?  I have remote desktop access, but would prefer not to have to deploy anything manually on them.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using Powershell with WMI. [This question] (https://superuser.com/questions/337810/how-can-i-remotely-install-or-uninstall-a-service-on-windows-server-2008-r2) discussed some approaches to install windows service remotely.